# RANN - algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, classification, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm having trouble understanding the RANN algorithm.

I read the article [A Randomized Approximate Nearest Neighbors
Algorithm](http://www.cs.yale.edu/publications/techreports/tr1434.pdf)
but I don't understand how I choose the k "suspects" in **point 5** in the algorithm (page 3).
I think that I search for them with the meadians I got while building the tree but I'm not sure.
And do I build the tree with the training set and in the same tree look for those "suspects" for each new example in the test set?

Also, would appriciate a pseudo code or a library.

**Algorithm's outline from the article:**

> 1. Choose a random rotation, acting on $\mathbb{R}^d$ , and rotate the $N$ given points.
> 2. Take the first coordinate, and divide the data set into two boxes, where the boxes are divided by finding the median in the first
>    coordinate.
> 3. On each box from Step 2, we repeat the subdivision on the second coordinate, obtaining four boxes in total.
> 4. We repeat this on coordinates 3, 4, etc., until each of the boxes has approximately k points.
> 5. We do a local search on the tree of boxes to obtain approximately $k$ ”suspects”, for each point ${x}_j$.
> 6. The above procedure is iterated T times, and for each point ${x}_j$, we select from the $T \cdot k$ ”suspects” the $k$ closest discovered points for
>    xj .
> 7. Perform a local graph search on the collections of suspects, obtained in Step 6 (we call this local graph search ”supercharging”).
>    Among $k^2$ ”candidates” obtained from the local graph search, we select
>    the best $k$ points and declare these ”the suspected approximate nearest
>    neighbors”, or ”suspects”.